# Is it fine if I see my application from Settings App in the emulator has Force Close option enabled even tough I have come out of my application?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have written a simple database program in android. It runs fine, there is no force close error. But I checked from my application from Settings App I see the Force Close option enabled, which implies that my application is still running in the background, even though I have completely came out from my application to the home screen by pressing back key. And moreover I am not using any services, alarm or broadcast things.

Can some one please guide me what may be the probable reason?. Or is it okay? Or will it crash if I put it on device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can some one please guide me what may be the probable reason?. Or is it okay? Or will it crash if I put it on device?

Your **application** is alive until Android OS needs more memory and destroys it. What I have understood does Android start destroying **activities** before killing the whole **application**. This means that your **application** can be alive even if you have finished your **activities**.

Do not worry about this; Android OS is handling this extremely well.